# CiviCRM Crowd Funding Extension

Tags: contributions, crowd-funding

I'm crowd sourcing features for, and people interested in, a Crowd Funding extension for CiviCRM.

I've made a head start which meets most of my needs. The work so far is open sourced: https://github.com/JohnFF/com.civifirst.crowdfunding/ this is being used and has been used for some time in a Production setting.

It has the following features:

1. Each Contribution can have a Parent Contribution (to be renamed
   "Target Contribution") which has an "accumulated funds" field.
2. The accumulated funds on the Parent Contribution is updated as Contributions with that Parent Contribution are added.
3. The status of the Parent Contribution is updated as funds are added in real time as well: from Pending, to Partially Paid, to
   Completed.
4. Any Event Participations dependent on that Parent Contribution have their status updated as well.

I want to add the following features:

5. A generic screen to display statuses of things being Crowd Funded for (I've made this bespoke for my needs, it's just not in the extension yet).
6. The ability to email all Contributors.
7. A hook for "upon Contribution" to let other extensions use the system.

I am mostly seeking requirements, suggestions, and co-maintainers. I am prepared to put up time and potentially cash as well.